# How the does this circuit source 4-20mA?

Tags: power-electronics, 4-20ma, powermosfet

[image]

In the circuit, how the mosfet flow the 4-20mA based on the resistor network?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a specific question, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: What is the voltage across R1? What does that tell you about its current? In turn, what  does that tell you about the current in R2?

Answer (score 1):

V1A/M2 is a voltage to current converter than converts the 1-5V input to 100uA to 500uA. That is reflected off the 24V rail to give -1V to -5V relative to the rail (which appears across R2).

V1B drives the MOSFET M1 to establish the same voltage across R3, which means that the output current is 4mA at 1V in and 20mA at 5V in, provided that a sufficiently low-resistance load is connected such that the MOSFET has a bit of voltage across it from source to drain.

Remember that, at DC, there is essentially no gate current so the source current equals the drain current.

Answer (score 0):

A typical 4-20 mA circuit has to work into a range of loads, anywhere from 50 ohms to several hundred.  The current sense resister will be floating at some voltage above ground depending on the current and the load resistance.  This causes a potential common mode error.  Calibrate the circuit at one load resistance and the calibration will be off at other load resistances.
There are a number of ways around this.  Using high precision matched resisters is one common way.  This circuit is another.  There are actually two current sense resisters (R1, R3) and neither see a common mode voltage.